# Snap window size to fixed multiples

Tags: c#, forms, resize

The Windows command console only allows you to resize the window to a multiple of the character size. This "snapping" of the window size is instantaneous and does not flicker. In native code, this is done by processing the `WM_SIZING` message and modifying the `RECT` structure accordingly.

In C#, I tried overriding the `OnResize` method, computing the "snapped" size, and setting the Form's `ClientSize` property accordingly. Unfortunately, the size keeps jumping between the snapped size and whatever size the cursor currently dictates.

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    int tgtCols = (ClientSize.Width + 4) / 8;
    int tgtLines = (ClientSize.Height + 8) / 15;
    if (cols != tgtCols || lines != tgtLines)
    {
        cols = tgtCols;
        lines = tgtLines;
        int tgtWidth = cols * 8;
        int tgtHeight = lines * 15;
        //ClientSize = new Size(tgtWidth, tgtHeight);
        Size = new Size(tgtWidth + exWidth, tgtHeight + exHeight);
    }
    base.OnResize(e);
}
```

As you can see, I've tried using both the `Size` and `ClientSize` properties, but both yield the same effect. Is there a better way of constraining the size? Or do I need to manually intercept the `WM_SIZING` message?

**EDIT**: I also tried manually intercepting `WM_SIZING`, but I get the same result:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_SIZING:
            DoSizeSnap(ref m);
            m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
            break;

        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}

private unsafe void DoSizeSnap(ref Message m)
{
    int edge = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    RECT *pRect = (RECT *)m.LParam.ToPointer();
    int tgtCols = (pRect->right - pRect->left - exWidth + 4) / 8;
    int tgtLines = (pRect->bottom - pRect->top - exHeight + 8) / 15;
    if (cols != tgtCols || lines != tgtLines)
    {
        cols = tgtCols;
        lines = tgtLines;
        int tgtWidth = cols * 8;
        int tgtHeight = lines * 15;
        // TODO: handle edge
        pRect->right = pRect->left + tgtWidth + exWidth;
        pRect->bottom = pRect->top + tgtHeight + exHeight;
    }
}
```

Subscribing to the `Resize` event doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks like your solution [should work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx).  Have you tried subscribing to the `Resize` event instead?

Comment: @Zer0 same thing happens. Trying the square sizing example you linked to seems to work, albeit with flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the statement `if (cols != tgtCols || lines != tgtLines)`. This causes the size snapping to occur only when the target lines/columns changes, *not* when the window width/height changes. This was to prevent infinite recursion, but the `Resize` event is not fired if the size does not actually change, so the `if` statement is unnecessary.